# Query to pull unique qty of an item

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table:

| item | qty | area |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 12 | AAA |
| 1234 | 11 | BBB |
| 1234 | 10 | CCC |
| 5678 | 5 | AAA |
| 4578 | 10 | AAA |
| 852 | 8 | AAA |
| 852 | 9 | BBB |
| 852 | 10 | CCC |

And the expected result to show only item available only in area AAA no other area

| item | qty | area |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5678 | 5 | AAA |
| 4578 | 10 | AAA |

I was trying to use the below query but the result was not sufficient as it give all the item in AAA not the unique ones I am looking for

```
select
  item
  , coalesce(sum(case when area = 'AAA' then qty end ) ,0) as 'AAA'
from MyTable
group by item
```

Comment: `GROUP BY item HAVING MIN(area) = 'AAA' and MAX(area) = 'AAA'`

Comment: Will there ever be 2 records for the item and area?  If so, a sum is still required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps.  In the CASE expression, using "else 0" will avoid nulls and the warning message about them being eliminated.

```
WITH MyTable as (
    SELECT * 
    FROM (
        VALUES
            ('1234', 12, 'AAA'),
            ('1234', 11, 'BBB'),
            ('1234', 10, 'CCC'),
            ('5678', 5, 'AAA'),
            ('4578', 10, 'AAA'),
            ('852', 8, 'AAA'),
            ('852', 9, 'BBB'),
            ('852', 10, 'CCC')
        ) t (item, qty, area) 
)
SELECT item, coalesce(sum(case when area = 'AAA' then qty else 0 end ) ,0) as 'AAA'
from MyTable
group by item 
having count(*) = 1
```

[Edit] This also works, but I think Dale's answer is still better.

```
SELECT item, SUM(qty) as 'AAA'
from MyTable
group by item 
having count(*) = 1 AND MIN(area) = 'AAA'
```

Comment: @Randy, if I have a big table of 10K lines shall I need them to the value sequence ?

Comment: @David, I don't understand the question.  If you are looking for all "singular" records, then remove the MIN(area) = 'AAA' in the WHERE clause and update the expression in the sum to sum all values.  It's just one value, but an aggregate is required.  You can return MIN(area) as a column to identify the area for the quantity.  If you need a column for each area, that's a different question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to check that no other `area` exists for the same `item`.

```
select item, qty, area
from MyTable mt1
where area = 'AAA'
and not exists (
    select 1
    from MyTable mt2
    where mt2.item = mt1.item and mt2.Area <> 'AAA'
);
```

Comment: appriciated the support; would pls advice what's the reason you use select 1 ?, thx